# Checking the duplicate key value present inside json array using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to check if the duplicate key value present inside the json array using Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
 var result=[{
          "email":'a@gmail.com',
          "title":'hello',
          "start":'yes'
        },{
          "email":'a@gmail.com',
          "title":'hello',
          "start":'yes'
        },{
          "email":'b@gmail.com',
          "title":'ggggg',
          "start":'No'
        },{
          "email":'g@gmail.com',
          "title":'hel',
          "start":'No'
        },{
          "email":'b@gmail.com',
          "title":'ggggg',
          "start":'No'
        }];
    if (result.length > 0) {
        angular.forEach(result,function(obj2){
            var data={'title':obj2.mname,'start':obj2.date};
            evtArr.push(data);
        })
    }
```

Here my requirement is before pushing the data into `evtArr` it will check the duplicate value using the `key- email` if one set of value belongs to one email (`i.e-a@gmail.com`) is already pushed into `evtArr` then other will remove.

Comment: Basically you want to remove duplicates? Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: If you like underscore, `evtArr = _.uniq(result, "email")` will work great

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` and create an object using `email` as key and object as value. Take out all the values from the object using `Object.values()`.

```js
var result=[{ "email":'a@gmail.com', "title":'hello', "start":'yes' },{ "email":'a@gmail.com', "title":'hello', "start":'yes' },{ "email":'b@gmail.com', "title":'ggggg', "start":'No' },{ "email":'g@gmail.com', "title":'hel', "start":'No' },{ "email":'b@gmail.com',"title":'ggggg', "start":'No' }],
    output = Object.values(result.reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.email] = Object.assign({},o);
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below is a simple and easy to understand solution for you.

First, push only the results into `resultFinal` array if the result with same email is not already pushed into that array.

```
let resultFinal = [];

result.forEach((resI) => {
  if (resultFinal.findIndex(resF => resF.email === resI.email) === -1) {
    resultFinal.push(result);
  }
});
```

After you have your `resultFinal` array, run a map and return objects comprising only of `title` and `start` for each of the elements.

```
resultFinal = resultFinal.map((resF) => {
  return {title: resultf.title, start: resultf.start};
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code.understand easily

```
var result = [{
                "email": 'a@gmail.com',
                "title": 'hello',
                "start": 'yes'
            }, {
                "email": 'a@gmail.com',
                "title": 'hello',
                "start": 'yes'
            }, {
                "email": 'b@gmail.com',
                "title": 'ggggg',
                "start": 'No'
            }, {
                "email": 'g@gmail.com',
                "title": 'hel',
                "start": 'No'
            }, {
                "email": 'b@gmail.com',
                "title": 'ggggg',
                "start": 'No'
            }];
            if (result.length > 0) {
                var ArrayPush = [];
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var obj = {}
                    obj.email = result[i].email;
                    obj.title = result[i].title;
                    obj.start = result[i].start;
                    var Getdistinctdate=ArrayPush.filter(function(element){
                        return element.email==result[i].email;
                    });
                    if(Getdistinctdate.length==0){
                        ArrayPush.push(obj);
                    }

                }

            }
```